# Where to put and handle recaptcha in native android under Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture?

Tags: android, architecture, recaptcha, clean-architecture

Where to put and handle recaptcha and api in native android under Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture?

Should the recaptcha api be put under the data layer and I make an interactor for between data and presentation layer?

Answer (score 0):

In Clean Architecture all "frameworks" are located in the outer most circle. I am not an android expert but as far as I understood recaptcha library also falls into this category.

Depending on whether u need to access recaptcha library from use case interactors or controllers you need to create an interface on that particular layer which is then implemented in the "frameworks" layer. This implementation wraps the recaptcha library and so respects the dependency rule.

**Update:** For a more detailed discussion on "how to integrate frameworks in Clean Architecture" pls refer to my blog post http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Frameworks/